# How can I convert a binary number to a base-4 number with a Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines, base-conversion

I'm looking for some guidance to get me going. I assume (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that it'll need 2 tapes and by reading various resources, I found that it might be easier with the binary string reversed.

In any programming language, I would first convert the binary string to decimal, but is this needed/a good idea?

Also, how many states would I need?

Any kind of articles, or hints on the subject would be much appreciated!

Comment: I hope that if you implement it in a programming language you *don't* first convert it to decimal. To convert from base 2 to base 4, all you need to do is to group bits in pairs. For example, $(100101)_2 = (211)_4$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Wonderful! This makes the task a lot simpler than I thought. Thanks for the input!